# Оператор if в android

Tags: android, java, if

Еще раз здавствуйте. :)

Т.к. на мой вопрос про добавление имен никто не ответил (пока), придумал другой выход. Вот код:

```
GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324);
GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[] {
            new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324),
            new GeoPoint(55.881231, 37.636800),
            new GeoPoint(55.865430, 37.648020)
    };

GeoPoint nearest = GeoPoint.getNearestLocation(currentLocation,
            Arrays.asList(locations));

public void onClick(View view){
        TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.station_name);
        helloTextView.setText(nearest.toString());
    }
```

А что если добавить оператор if, типа

```
if (nearest.toString==55.895859, 37.719324)
{
            TextView TextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.station_name);
            TextView1.setText("точка1");
        }
```

Сам знаю, что неправильно, но можете помочь с исполнением? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант завести поле `String name` в классе `GeoPoint`, в конструкторе передавать имя в качестве параметра вместе с координатами, геттер написать.

```
private String name;

GeoPoint(double lat, double lan, Sting name){

     ...

     this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
     return name;
}
```

и использовать

```
GeoPoint locations[] = new GeoPoint[] {
            new GeoPoint(55.895859, 37.719324, "Точка1"),
            new GeoPoint(55.881231, 37.636800, "Точка2"),
            new GeoPoint(55.865430, 37.648020, "Точка3")
    };

TextView1.setText(nearest.getName());
```